# Ошибка при запуске программы

Tags: golang

При попытке запуска или компиляции программы выдает ошибки.
Перерыл весь русский интернет ничего похожего не нашел.
Система Win10. Программа начальная Hello world, ошибаться там негде.
Если кто то поможет , буду очень благодарен.

```
C:\Go\src\golang-book\chapter2>go build main1.go
# runtime
..\..\runtime\mstkbar.go:244:41: undefined: stkbar
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:16:17: surrogateMin redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:49:17
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:17:17: surrogateMax redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:50:17
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:21:7: t1 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:31:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:22:7: tx redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:32:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:23:7: t2 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:33:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:24:7: t3 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:34:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:25:7: t4 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:35:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:26:7: t5 redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:36:33
..\..\runtime\utf8.go:28:10: maskx redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at ..\..\runtime\rune.go:43:24
..\..\runtime\mstkbar.go:244:41: too many errors
```

Код программы:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main()  {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

Решение:

```
Такие ошибки вылезают если поверх старой версии go (например 1.8) распаковать/установить более новую версию. Структура файлов стандартной библиотеки меняется от версии к версии, поэтому ставить go в каталог где уже установлена предыдущая версия go нельзя. Полностью удалите каталог в котором установлен go и после этого установите его заново.
```

Все заработало. Анинсталил сам GO, удалил папку с остатками, скачал с офф сайта последнюю инсталяшку и все запустилось.
Спасибо kvark128

Comment: Приведите пример кода программы.

Comment: Если у вас Хелловорлд такое выдаёт, у вас что-то с инсталляцией. Допишите в вопрос, как устанавливали го.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие ошибки вылезают если поверх старой версии go (например 1.8) распаковать/установить более новую версию.
Структура файлов стандартной библиотеки меняется от версии к версии, поэтому ставить go в каталог где уже установлена предыдущая версия go нельзя.
Полностью удалите каталог в котором установлен go и после этого установите его заново.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все заработало.  Скорее всего намудрил при инсталляции.